# Create inserts for particular employees data in multiple tables before deleting via CASCADE - Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

Create inserts for particular employees data in multiple tables before deleting via CASCADE.Say employee 'KING' has 1 record in Parent table and has around 3-7 records in multiple child tables (say 32 tables).

I need to back up his data from multiple tables as inserts in single automated process before deleting the data for his records.

When I delete from parent table since there is CASCADE ON , in single shot entire data associated to KING from multiple child tables say 32 tables gets deleted.

But for worst case if I need to revert back is there any smart way to save INSERTS of this data prior to deletion ?

Comment: Look at triggers. You need to create before delete triggers to populate your archive or history tables with data being deleted. There are tons of examples in Oracle documentation, here and online in general.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs.I have no option to create triggers.(Because of performance issues)

Comment: What will trigger your code when row is deleted??? You can replace triggers with procedures but then how would you run it? Manually? Only triggers will do the job, nothing else.

Comment: I can run stored procedure manually to get those inserts , every time if I need to delete occurrence of particular employees data across multiple tables.Is there some stored proc for the same ?

Comment: I doubt if you can run manually. Unless! There is some event, like button in your front end or smth else that will trigger your procedures. You need an event that will tell you your records are being deleted and you need to insert data before it is deleted. But if you can then OK, make some procedures that will insert into your history/archive tables.It is simple insert into your tables BEFORE data is deleted. You may also consider PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION in your code. It is easy, just read. I do not know your exact requirements...

Comment: I think you are getting confused on the requirement ? It is manual process , the criteria is to get a backup of data that is being deleted via CASCADE. Say if I delete 5 Primary key records and due to cascade if it deletes 100 records from child tables , I need to save this 105 Inserts before running the delete.All this is manual process. Say if there are only 5 tables I can manually take those inserts , but if there are 55 tables involved because of cascade the process to backup manually is cumbersome :(

Comment: Maybe. But I'm still sure you need triggers. I cannot read minds, i do not know what exactly means "When I delete from parent table... " If you delete smth, Oracle needs to know that record is being deleted. Oracle has built in mechanism for this. The rest is up to you. I do not see many people paid attn to your question. I think it is obvious for them also. Good luck!